# how to reposition div placed over image

Tags: jquery, image, textbox, image-resizing

Re-editing my question with more information

I am using Jquery. 
Let me explain what exactly i am truing to achieve.

The page loads an image with tool picker on the side available to insert element over the image (imagine like mspaint) like text box, caption etc....
There will be an option to re-size / move the image given the div size be limited based on user screen. 
So i put a text box at one location, and when user moves/ re-size the image, i should make sure that the text box over the image also re-sizes as if it is sticking on the image.

Comment: would appreciate why it is being voted non-constructive. Even it is a stupid question i am trying to understand. Thanks!!!

Comment: probably the lack of information. DO you already have the image re-sizing working? If so how is that implemented? That's important to give you a good answer. Quick thought from me would be to put the image in a container div, possible as a background. Then put a text area inside that that's position absolute top/left/bottom/right = 0. Now it's the same size as the image.

Comment: Many ppl vote non-constructive without an explanation, it's frustrating when U don't know why.

Comment: I have provided more information.
It makes more sense if folks give a online comment why exactly my question is non-constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible. Using jQuery UI's .resizable() method, you could capture the image's height, and width in a variable on resize. Then you would simply apply that height, and width to the textarea relatively.

Kind of like this:

```
$("img").resizable({
    resize: function (event, ui) {
        $('textarea').css({ 
            'height': $(this).height(),
            'width': $(this).width()
        });
    }
});
```

Here is a **very basic** working example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/C6F9Z/)

Comment: Thank you for one suggestion.

Comment: Are you using jQueryUI for resizing?

Comment: Yes i am using Jquery. But let me tell you what exactly my intent was. The page loads an image with tool picker on the side avaiable to insert element over the image. like text box captio etc. There will be an option to re-size / move the image given the container size be limited based on user screen. So when i put a text box at one location, so when user moves/ re-size the image, i should make sure that the text box over the image also re-sizes as if it is sticking on the image.

Comment: That makes sense. There are definitely several methods or approaches you could take to this. I hope when you start your project, this helped in some way.